# Combinatorial optimization and graph coloring

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory, combinatorial-geometry

I am considering the following problem:

(i) Fix $n$ and color the edges of $K_n$ red and blue arbitrarily.

(ii) Let $M$ be the set of monochromatic triangles in $K_n$ and define $g:M\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as $g(T_{xyz})$= $|N_r(x)\cap N_r(y)\cap N_r(z)|$ if $T_{xyz}$ is red and $|N_b(x)\cap N_b(y)\cap N_b(z)|$ otherwise. Here $T_{xyz}$ is a monochromatic triangle with vertices $x$, $y$ and $z$.

(iii) Consider the problem Max $g(T_{xyz})$ s.t. $T_{xyz}\in M$. What is a lower bound for this maximum?

Any advice as to how this problem may be tackled would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Update: As per a conjecture of A. Thomason (1979) $r(K_m+\bar{K_n})\le 2^m(m+n-2)+2$ where $r(G)$ is the diagonal ramsey number.

Comment: Isn't this maximized by taking all red or all blue?

Comment: The graph has been colored arbitrarily. My question is how much is this max-value at least? I have edited the question.

Comment: It is linear in $n$ (since we have about $Cn^4$ monochromatic full quadrilaterals, so one of $n(n-1)(n-2)/6$ triangles belongs to at least $24C\cdot n$ of them). Are you interested in sharp constant or in exact value for each $n$?

Comment: What does $N_r(x)$ mean?

Comment: Can you solve the problem for some small values of $n$ and then look up the results in the Online Encyclopedia of Integers Sequences? 

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: $N_r(x)$ is the red neighborhood of $x$, i.e. the vertices adjoined by red edges to $x$. I will do as you suggest.
@Fedor Petrov: I am interested in an exact value for each n. But could you expand your comment with a reference if possible?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I thought about what you said, but it isnt getting me anywhere. Also I have learnt of a conjecture by A. Thomason which essentially tells me that small values of n would just give 0 as the answer to my problem. (I am updating the question)

Comment: An easy observation is that if $n \ge R(m,m)$, which is asymptotically at least $(m2^{m/2}/e\sqrt{2})(1+o(1)), g \ge m-3$ eg. if $n>=18=R(4,4),g>0$.
$n \ge 18=r(4,4)$, $g>0$. 

Comment: There are examples where $g(T) = n/4$ for all triangles. Not sure if that's the minimum, but I suspect it is. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear lower bound. For any 18 vertices we have a monochromatic quadrilateral by Ramsey theorem. It follows that the total number of monochromatic quadrilaterals is not less then ${n\choose 18}/{n-4\choose 14}$. Then one of triangles is contained in at least at least $4{n\choose 18}/({n-4\choose 14}\cdot {n\choose 3})=(n-3)/{18\choose 4}$ monochromatic quadrilaterals.